# How can I export a default object with interfaces in it in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, export, vite

```
import A from './A';
import type { AProps } from './A';

import B from './B';
import type { BProps } from './B';

export default {
    A, AProps,
    B, BProps
}
```

I want to export a default object with `interfaces` inside it.

The code above causes exception under vite because `AProps` and `BProps` variables are not defined in the output js file.

I tried another way which can solve this problem:

```
export A from './A';
export type { AProps } from './A';

export B from './B';
export type { BProps } from './B';
```

And use `import * as X from './xx'`. But I prefer to use `import X from './xx'`, which means I have to export a default value from the file.

Then I create another file with code `export * as default from './xx'` in it and it's working well.

My question is if I can put all the `export` code in a single file?

Comment: You would need to use a namespace but that's icky...

Comment: @vera. yes, I don't like using namespace if it's not necessary.

Comment: Well, what your describing _is_ a namespace.

Comment: @AlexWayne I prefer using esmodule syntax to using typescript namespace, so I'm asking for a way to implement my requirement with pure esmodule syntax. If it's impossible I'll use typescript namespace.